# Регулярное выражение: Замена символа с сохранением регистра

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "My name is Adam";
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\s]", "x"); 
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

где производится замена всех символов на `x` маленькую, кроме всех пробельных и непробельных символов, включая символ новой строки `(\s)`.

Результат: `"xx xxxx xx xxxx"`

Я попробовал различные варианты, и у меня не получается теперь **сохранить регистр символа, т.е. чтобы маленькие буквы были заменены на `x` маленькую, а большие буквы на `X` большую**. Например:

чтобы это: `"My name is Adam"` стало этим: `"Xx xxxx xx Xxxx"`

Comment: А почему именно через регулярку? Пробежаться по StringBuilder будет быстрее, думаю.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не обязательно использовать регулярное выражение, мне как-раз таки скорость важна, т.к. этот модуль серверной части и идет многомиллионная обработка текстов.

Comment: Написал ответом свой вариант, попробуйте сравнить в бенчмарках :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заглавные буквы Юникода можно найти с помощью `\p{Lu}`, все остальные символы, которые нужно заменить можно отловить с помощью `\S` (любой непробельный символ).

Решение, заменяющее все символы за один проход:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\p{Lu})|\S", m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? "X" : "x");
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/7jszt8):

```
var s = "My name is Adam";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\p{Lu})|\S", m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? "X" : "x");
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => Xx xxxx xx Xxxx
```

Шаблон `(\p{Lu})|\S` находит и помещает в группу №1 заглавную букву Юникода, а если это другой символ, отличный от пробельного символа, просто помещает его в буфер совпадения. `m.Groups[1].Success ? "X" : "x"` заменяет совпадение `X`, если группа №1 сработала (не пуста), или `x`, если сработало `\S`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно (нужно!) использовать [юникодные категории](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories).

```
string text = "My name is Adam. Моё имя Адам.";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Ll}", "x");
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Lu}", "X");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

`Ll` - означает маленькие буквы любых алфавитов.
`Lu` - большие буквы любых алфавитов.

Если нужно не только буквы, но вообще все знаки, кроме пробельных и больших букв, заменить на `x`, то

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\p{Lu}\s]", "x");
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Lu}", "X");
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "My name is Adam";

        // английские буквы
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[a-z]", "x");
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[A-Z]", "X");

        // русские буквы
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[а-яё]", "x");
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[А-ЯЁ]", "X");

        Console.WriteLine(text);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: А как добавить еще замену русских символов? Попытался так: `@"[a-zа-я]", "x"`, но что-то не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам важна скорость, то рекомендую попробовать такой вариант, он должен работать быстрее регулярок:

```
string text = "My name is Adam. Моё имя Адам.";
var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; ++i)
    if (char.IsLetter(sb[i]))
        if (char.IsLower(sb[i]))
            sb[i] = 'x';
        else
            sb[i] = 'X';
text = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

т.е. пробегаем по строке и просто заменяем буквы в нижнем регистре на `'x'`, а в верхнем - на `'X'`, ничего сложного.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я до этого не был знаком с такими вещами как `char.IsLetter()`. Но скорость обработки оказалась такая же как у решения @Wiktor Stribiżew.